# How can one identify a private list view?

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, list-view

After placing a list on a webpart page and modifying the view, I found that my user could not see all of the columns that were visible to me. I can only guess that I was looking at a private view. It turned out that his visible columns on the page were exactly those of the list's default view.

Is there a way to look at a page and know whether what I see is a private or public list view?

I worked around this by giving the user a link directly to the named view he needs instead of a page with a view inserted. However, I'd still like to know how I can tell whether I'm looking at what my user sees on a page.

Comment: Which sharepoint version are you using?

Comment: Enterprise 2010.

Answer (score 2):

here's a programmatic approach:

```
$fooWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity $fooURL
$fooView = $fooWeb.GetViewFromUrl($fooViewURL) 
$fooView.PersonalView # boolean property for personalized (private) view..
```

checking the private view again with SPList.DefaultView Property will reconfirm that it is a private view (default views can't be private).

Another approach: Check this code segment for [Accessing Personal View in Sharepoint List](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/MS-SharePoint/Q_26823629.html)

Comment: Good information, thanks. However, I don't do anything server-side. Strictly SPD and browser, so I'm still seeking a way to modify a view in one of those tools and be able to tell whether it's public or not. The specific problem occurred with "Edit the current view" while editing the web part on the page.

Comment: ok.. added tag for SharePoint-Designer to the question